# pandoc conflict

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, pandoc

Im trying to use some pandocs templates, but it throws an error and I can't correct it.

Template:[IEEE Paper Template for Pandoc](https://github.com/stsewd/ieee-pandoc-template).

The requirementa are installled, but either running `make` or by hand with:

```
pandoc -o build/paper.pdf --bibliography=bibliography.bib --csl=bibliography.csl --filter pandoc-citeproc -s -f markdown --template=template.latex paper.md metadata.yaml
```

But this gives the next error

```
!  LaTeX Error: Environment cslreferences undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.145 \begin{cslreferences}
```

Bibtex is installled and I do not what file as at line 145 the cslreferebces, how can be fixed?
Thanks.

Comment: According to your `make` call your template does not use a LaTeX way of generating the references (BibTeX or `biblatex`): It uses a CSL-based way, where citations are processed by a pandoc module before being passed on to LaTeX.

Comment: I found https://github.com/stsewd/ieee-pandoc-template/issues/12, which links https://github.com/mpark/wg21/issues/54#issuecomment-569867462.

Comment: The suggested method throws more errors, so simply update the pandoc version and support libraries. Thanks @moewe